# Removing rows that don't contain strings from csv file, using one-line reg exp grep/sed

Tags: regex, file, sed, grep

I have *idsfile.csv* which is a comma separated file of ids (with no new line characters in), 
and I would like to grab only the lines from a second datafile.txt file 
which have one of those ids in (surrounded by tabs).

Sample idsfile.csv:

```
000001,000002,000005,000007,000008,000009,000011,000021,000029,000040,...
```

Sample datafile.txt:

```
titl e1   000001   description1 
title2   000003   descr iption2 
ti tle3   000021   des cripti on3 
title4   000023   description4
```

If I was doing this without having to read in the ids from a file I would try:

```
grep -Ev '/\t000001\t|\t000002\t|\t000003\t/' datafile.txt > output.txt
```

but I am unsure how to read in the comma separated values in a way that I could then use them in the regular expression.

Does anyone know how I might assemble this as a one line command query please? Perhaps with textscan?

Edit: Actually, if I changed idsfile.csv to have an id on each line (with a tab before and after), then would I line similar to this work please or, I expect, is the syntax quite wrong:

```
grep -Evf idsfile.csv datafile.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single line of data in idsfile.csv is hostile to this workflow - you will have to transform it into a series of lines.  The Unix toolset is based around lines!

So, we need to transliterate the commas into newlines:

```
tr , '\012' < idsfile.csv > idsfile.lines
fgrep -f idsfile.lines datafile.txt
```

A POSIX-compliant 'grep' will also recognize:

```
grep -F -f idsfile.lines datafile.txt
```

You might even be able to get away with:

```
tr , '\012' < idsfile.csv |
grep -F -f - datafile.txt
```

This tells 'grep' to read the list of names to search for from its standard input.

Finally, if you're using GNU grep, you could add '`-w`' to search for words - it will require the pattern to be surrounded by non-alphanumeric characters (spaces in the examples).
The '`-w'` option means that if a line in datatfile.txt contains

```
something 000002100  kkkk
```

the entry '000021' will not select that line (without the '`-w`', it would be selected).

Comment: Ah brilliant, thank you. That sounds like what I'm looking for. I can change the csv file to output per line with tabs round it (as it should have tabs round in the data file).. and datafile.txt is about 70Mb so fairly large. I will give that a go now.

Comment: So I could just use the following?: grep -F -f -w idsfile.lines datafile.txt

Comment: @Don: not quite. `grep -F -w -f idsfile.lines datafile.txt`.  The '-f file' option specifies that the named file (or standard input if using '-f -') contains the patterns to be searched for.  The '-F' tells grep to behave like 'fgrep' (no metacharacters).  And the '-w' is explained in the answer.

Comment: The only problem I see with your code is that it completely ignores the tabs.  Your code would match `foo_000001_bar` where `_` are white spaces.

Comment: @SiegeX: yes, that is technically a valid criticism. Whether it matters will be an issue for the OP to decide. With the one-line input, using `tr` to get the newlines in place, feeding that to `sed` to add tabs before and after the match, and then feeding that to `fgrep` or `grep -F` would do the trick: `tr , '\012' <idsfile.csv | sed 's/.*/[tab]&[tab]/' | grep -F -f - datafile.txt` (where '`[tab]`' denotes an actual tab character). To my mind, the key point is the observation that the original input (a single line of CSV) has to be transformed before it can be used; the rest is then details.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sed` to convert the contents of  idsfile.csv into a regular expression for use with grep.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was just thinking perhaps something along those lines, but would the query then be rep -Evf please?

Comment: Just pipe the output of sed into grep.

Answer (score 1):

The following 1-liner uses `awk` to turn each field of the csv file into a list of regex for `grep` to match via the `-f` option.  We then use Bash's *process substitution* syntax `<( )` to treat the output of the `awk` command as a file (named pipe).

```
$ grep -w -f <(awk -v 'RS=,|\n' '{print "\t"$0"\t"}' sample.csv) title.txt
```

#### Input

```
$ cat sample.csv
000001,000003,000005,000007,000008,000009,000011,000023,000029

$ cat title.txt
titl e1 000001  description1
title2  000003  descr iption2
ti tle3 000021  des cripti on3
title4  000023  description4
```

#### Output

```
$ grep -w -f <(awk -v 'RS=,|\n' '{print "\t"$0"\t"}' sample.csv) title.txt
titl e1 000001  description1
title2  000003  descr iption2
title4  000023  description4
```

*Note* that the line containing `000021` did not match.  Also not apparent is that each 6-digit number in title.txt are surrounded by tabs, not spaces.

Comment: Not all versions of 'sed' support the '\t\n' in the substitute.  My answer used '\n', but the MacOS X version of 'sed' would have nothing to do with it - not even when I tried '\\n'.  So, I rewrote my answer.  Both the Mac man page and the POSIX specification of sed say _'The escape sequence '\n' shall match a <newline> embedded in the pattern space. A literal <newline> shall not be used in the BRE of a context address or in the substitute function.'_

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: good call on the non-POSIX'ness of a newline in the replacement text. Replaced it with a call to `awk` instead. Also added the `-w` option for good measure.

Comment: @Jonathan: That's a *literal* newline, not an *escaped* literal newline. To improve readability, you could store a newline in a variable. Reading further: *"A line can be split by substituting a <newline> into it. The application shall escape the <newline> in the replacement by preceding it by a <backslash>."*

Comment: @Dennis: OK...yes; that seemed to work with '`echo a,c,b,d | sed 's/,/\\[NL]/g'`' where '[NL]' indicates an actual newline.  Not sure about whether the 'a literal newline shall not be used in the BRE of ... the substitute function' is being contravened.  In many ways, though, '`tr`' is the better tool for the transliteration operation anyway - but with the appropriate modification, the 'sed' based solution could have stood (my answer - not sure about this one, but probably this one too).  One advantage of 'tr' over 'sed'; it is not limited by line-length at all, whereas 'sed' could be.